# Loop in Render function of ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

may I know what's wrong with the code below?  I think something is wrong in the loop for the `<TextNote>` tag, but I can't tell what is wrong as there is no error message.  Thanks

*EDIT* FYI, only the button is rendered, the TextNote is not rendered at all. TextNote is another JS file and it works perfectly by itself.

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="textBoard">
    {this.state.textNotes.forEach( (note) => {
      return (<TextNote key={note.id}
                  id={note.id}
                  onChange={this.update}
                  onRemove={this.remove}>
              {note.note}
      </TextNote>)
    }
    )}
    <button onClick={() => this.add('New Text')}>ADD</button>
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: Hi Victor - What is the result that you're getting, and what is the result you're expecting?

Comment: "I think something is wrong" --- why do you think it is?

Comment: "the TextNote is not rendered at all" --- that's because `Array.prototype.forEach` returns nothing, you wanted `Array.prototype.map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't take `return`. Use `map` instead.

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="textBoard">
    {this.state.textNotes.map( (note) => {
      return (<TextNote key={note.id}
                  id={note.id}
                  onChange={this.update}
                  onRemove={this.remove}>
              {note.note}
      </TextNote>)
    }
    )}
    <button onClick={() => this.add('New Text')}>ADD</button>
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get it working with `forEach` method also, but in a bit different way.

```
render(){
  const items = [];
  this.state.textNotes.forEach((note) => {
    items.push(<TextNote // instead of return push it in an array
                 key={note.id}
                 id={note.id}
                 onChange={this.update}
                 onRemove={this.remove}>
                {note.note}
              </TextNote>
  })
  return <div>
    {items}
  </div>
}
```

I also suggest using `map` instead of `forEach`, hope it will help you